# Fill remaining horizontal width without a fixed width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to float two elements and make the second element fill the remaining width space using only CSS, but the more answers & research I do looks like I might need to use JS.

I'm trying to float text with a variable width next to `span` which I want to fill the remaining space.

```css
ul#filter-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
ul#filter-list span {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: l margin: 0px 5px;
}
span.filter-pill {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="filter-list">
  <li>
    <a href="{{ route('question.index') }}">
      <span>All</span>
      <span style="background: #5fbeaa" class="filter-pill"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{{ route('question.index') }}">
      <span>a big filter name here</span>
      <span style="background: #5fbeaa" class="filter-pill"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1466qdab/

Note with the width set to 100% it falls to the line under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), it can be pretty easy:

```
ul#filter-list a {
  display: flex;
}
```

In addition, use `align-items: center;` for centering vertically.

```css
ul#filter-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
ul#filter-list a {
  display: flex; /*added*/
  align-items: center; /*added*/
}
ul#filter-list span {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
span.filter-pill {
  flex: 1; /*added*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="filter-list">
  <li>
    <a href="{{ route('question.index') }}">
      <span>All</span>
      <span style="background: #5fbeaa" class="filter-pill"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{{ route('question.index') }}">
      <span>a big filter name here</span>
      <span style="background: #5fbeaa" class="filter-pill"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Aha I've not seen flexbox before, that works almost perfectly the only issue is long titled names like the one in the example break onto a new line. Is there a way to force the text to stay on a single line?

Comment: Well you can remove `width:100%;` from `span.filter-pill`, and add `flex:1`.

Comment: Thats perfect, I'll look into flex more for the future. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @andyjones added link to the support tables.